# Bucketing ranks values in r

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape, data-transform

I am trying to bucket rank values in cycles. From rank 1 to rank 2 is cycle1, similarly from rank 2 to rank 3 is cycle2, so on forth and create binary values for each cycle (as shown  below)

## Data frame before

```
id               event              date                   rank       
1241a21ef        one             2016-08-13 20:03:37         1
1241a21ef        two             2016-08-15 05:41:09         2
12426203b        two             2016-08-04 05:35:10         1
12426203b       three            2016-08-06 02:07:41         2
12426203b        two             2016-08-10 05:42:33         3
12426203b       three            2016-08-14 02:43:16         4
```

## Data frame after

```
id           cycle1     cycle2   cycle3
1241a21ef      1          0         0
12426203b      1          1         1
```

Note: Each group( that is id) has unique rank value based on the time stamp and the rank will be reset to 1 for the next new id

Comment: Is it possible for `rank` to repeat? Meaning for a given `id` rank will change from `4 to 1`. If yes, then which cycle will that be?

Comment: Each group( that is id)  has unique rank value based on the time stamp. Yes the rank will change from 4 to 1 but for the subsequent group ( i.e for a different id). Meaning the rank will be reset to 1 for the next  new id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dplyr::count` along with `tidyr::spread` to get data tabulated in desired format as:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(id, rank) %>%   
  filter(rank != last(rank)) %>%   #drop last rank for each id
  mutate(cycle = paste0("cycle", rank)) %>%  #desired column names after spread
  group_by(id, cycle) %>%
  count() %>%
  spread(key = cycle, value = n, fill = 0) %>%
  as.data.frame() 





#          id cycle1 cycle2 cycle3
# 1 1241a21ef      1      0      0
# 2 12426203b      1      1      1
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text =
"id               event              date                   rank       
1241a21ef        one             '2016-08-13 20:03:37'         1
1241a21ef        two             '2016-08-15 05:41:09'         2
12426203b        two             '2016-08-04 05:35:10'         1
12426203b       three            '2016-08-06 02:07:41'         2
12426203b        two             '2016-08-10 05:42:33'         3
12426203b       three            '2016-08-14 02:43:16'         4",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks MKR. It worked. Really appreciate your help. I learned a couple of new things today.

Comment: @ajax Glad to know. Actually if your data is not ordered then you can use `arrange` before taking `diff`. Again, use of `diff` can be avoided if your `rank` is sequential. You have to just drop the row with `max` rank.